# Unable to access the click event of a button in Angular

Tags: angular

I’m creating a login page in Angular, but every time I click on the “Log-in” button, I am unable to send my http request and the page gets refreshed. I think I am unable to access the click event of my button.

```
<form class="form-container">
  <div>
    <b><h2>LOG-IN</h2></b>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type=“text" class="form-control” (keyup)="onInput($event,'usr')">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" (keyup)="onInput($event,'pwd')">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-block" (click)="login()">Log-in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

My .ts file looks like this:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  user: any;

  usrnm: string;
  psswd: string;

  constructor(private service: UsersService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onInput(event: any, lbl: string) {
    if (lbl === 'usr') {
      this.usrnm = event.target.value;
      console.log(this.usrnm.valueOf());
    }
    else {
      this.psswd = event.target.value;
      console.log(this.psswd.valueOf());
    }
  }

  login() {
    console.log(this.usrnm.valueOf());
    this.service.getUser(this.usrnm.valueOf()).subscribe((response : any) => {
      console.log(response);
    }, error => {
      alert('An unexpected error occured.');
      console.log(error);
    }); 
  }
}
```

I have noticed that onInput() works but login() does not give any output in the console. I just don’t know what is wrong.

Comment: this doesnot look me angular way to do. Please find some online examples.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u73hlp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: you need check getUser method

Comment: The getUser() http service works well, it was the button that caused the problem. I just had to go back to a bit of javascript and add ```event.preventDefault();``` in the login(). It’s all solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to my coding books and went through some javascript code, where I found that the page refreshed because of of “submit”. Instead it recommended using `event.preventDefault();` in login(), and that solved my problem.

Comment: Also you could have set your button type to `button`: `type="button"`. Inside a form, if you don't do it, it defaults to `type="submit"`

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned some of your bootstrap classes to better see your code.
I added `type="submit"` to the login button

now your button works !
please check this [stackblitz](https://angular-jf2hb7.stackblitz.io)

**EDIT**
please also note your **double quotation marks** on the following line,

```
<input type=“text" class="form-control” (keyup)="onInput($event,'usr')">
```

you must change this `“` to this `"`

Comment: I did add ```type=“submit”``` but it continued to give me the same result with no change. So I went back to my books and went through some javascript code, where I found that the page refreshed because of of “submit”. Instead it recommended using ```event.preventDefault();``` in login(), and that solved my problem. Thanks for the answer!